# Solar astrophysics--flux derivation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astrophysics, sun

The question reads:

[image]

The solution reads:

[image]

My only answer is for 4 and it is $\pi I_\nu$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please do not repeatedly post the same question. You can edit the original to clarify it, but you should also not repeatedly edit in an effort to stay on the top of the active queue.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, if you read the contents of my post you'd see it's an expansion. Maybe prevent users from posting one line replies in place of constructive feedback we can learn?

Answer (score 0):

When you integrated, you ignored the fact that $I_\nu$ depends on $\theta$.

Comment: I've got this far: $\frac{1}{\kappa_\nu \rho} \frac{dB_\nu}{d\nu} \int \int -cos^2 \theta sin \theta d\theta d\phi$